# Linking to libiconv

Tags: xcode, macos, libmysql, libiconv

I've created a clean build of [libmariadbclient](https://downloads.mariadb.org/client-native/) and integrated it into my project. Whenever I try to build said project I fail with an error:

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_libiconv", referenced from:
      _mariadb_convert_string in libmariadbclient.a(my_charset.c.o)
  "_libiconv_close", referenced from:
      _mariadb_convert_string in libmariadbclient.a(my_charset.c.o)
  "_libiconv_open", referenced from:
      _mariadb_convert_string in libmariadbclient.a(my_charset.c.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

I then add `libiconvlib.dylid` to my project, cleaned it and tried to build again, but I still get the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a [bug report](https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/CONC-65) with the developers and the issue was promptly fixed.

Comment: How did they fix the problem? I'm having a similar issue on another project.

Comment: No idea, check their commit history. If you're using the MariaDB Connector-c, try downloading the source from github.

Comment: @ruipacheco The bug report says it was fixed in rev. 108 but it’s not obvious how that maps to commits in the source repository. Any idea?

Comment: Nope, sorry. But don't forget that there's other FOSS MySQL drivers out there.